# I have a Dell Precision T7600 can I take out one of the GPU and put in a gtx 480?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Dell Precision T7600 can I take out the Telsa card or Quadro card and replace it with my old gtx 480?  I want to play video games and I am having troubles finding if my motherboard supports the gtx 480.  Also is it better to take out the telsa or quadro card since I want to do video recording / rendering with the card left in?

Comment: Open it up and see! Ever play round peg goes in the round hole? Thats pretty much how building a computer goes, just check to see if you have a slot that matches the card. This is a server / workstation, so I am assuming that it will not :/ I tried doing the same in a Dell Poweredge with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

According to Dell's [spec sheet for this model](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell_Precision_T7600_Spec_Sheet.pdf), you can have up to 3 PCI-Express x16 cards in this system with up to 675 watt power draw, so adding a GTX 480 should not be difficult. Personally, I would remove any existing video card prior to installing a new one.

THe GTX 480 is a rather old card for gaming, you should look into a more recent model, it is not hard to exceed the capabilities of a 6 year old card with a modern card at even a moderate price. I suggest looking at http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/ for comparisons of video cards.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should be able to. They're all PCIe.

Whether the older card will be better is debatable. Quadros are apparently better at double precision mathematics. Tesla's are 'pure' GPGPUs so they would have the same advantages as a tesla.

I'd say test it, benchmark it and see ;)